# Как в telegram Durgerking bot реализована отправка данных в бот

Tags: javascript, node.js, telegram, бот, web-apps

Как в telegram Durgerking bot реализована отправка данных в бот, тогда как там используется inline кнопка. В веб приложении метод sendData не работает при открытии через inline  кнопки. Используется какой-то другой метод.